# SQL- filtering each query result differently

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question that has been driving me crazy. It seems like the answer should be possible (or even obvious), but I've been stumped up to this point.

Here is the context. I'm trying to figure out which of my users have logged in within the last 90 days of their product licenses expiring (now that they are no longer customers). The problem is, the filter is relative to when the licenses expire, which is different for each customer. I initially tried to write a query like this:

```
SELECT customer_id, email
FROM customers
WHERE last_login > ((SELECT license_end FROM customers)-7776000)
```

This is a unix timestamp for both last_login and license_end, so the 7776000 is the seconds conversion for 90 days. As I'm sure you've already identified, this subquery is going to return more than one row and fail. Oops.

So in this case, is there a way to return all of the IDs and emails that had a last_login timestamp within the last 30 days of their licenses ending, since each license end date will be different for each customer?

I know I can just do it in a spreadsheet, but this puzzle is driving me crazy. Thanks in advance for your expertise!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a subquery. You're simply comparing columns from the same row of the table.

```
SELECT customer_id, email
FROM customers
WHERE last_login > license_end - 7776000
```

Comment: I think my confusion came from the fact that I was trying to do a `((SELECT unix_timestamp(license_end) FROM customers)-7776000)`, but it turns out the `SELECT` and `FROM` were completely unnecessary. (That column is actually a timestamp, not in unix.) This definitely worked. Thanks!!

Comment: If both columns are timestamps, use `DATE_SUB()` to subtract an interval

Answer (score 0):

if these are really in the same customers table (which does not seem well normalized - but ok)

then you just need this

```
SELECT customer_id, email
FROM customers
WHERE last_login > license_end-7776000
```

Comment: Yeah these aren't actually in the same table, I just wanted to simplify for the spirit of the question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user7484388 If they aren't in the same table, you need to join the tables, then you can do `table1.last_login > table2.license_end - 7776000`